# Is this true way to send request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

i wonder if this is true and safe way to send request via ajax json type to php file or not ?!

note : it return success result ..

but my question if to keep them like this or change it to another safe method ?!

**Html Code**

```
<span class="clickable" data-bind={"name":"master","tag":"1"}>click</span>
```

**Javascript Code :**

```
$(".clickable").livequery('click touchstart', function (e)
{
    var bind = $(this).data("bind");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "page.php",
        data: bind,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response)
        {
             alert(response)
        }
    });
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

**PHP File :**

```
$name= mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['name'])))); 
if(!isset($name) ||  $name == '' ||  $name != 'master') {
  echo 'Error: Invalid Action';
  exit;
}else{ 
 // Do Something
}
```

Comment: yes... it looks fine...

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: If assigning directly from HTML, I suppose you'll need quotes around that JSON string to be syntactically correct..

Comment: The danger is in the server side, which you have not posted. Is this using SSL and is the data escaped are a few questions that spring to mind.

Comment: @Juhana , safe from XSS or other non-safe implement

Comment: @DanPower see the update about server side .. i'm using `mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($name))));`
to escape data ..

Comment: Your `data-bind` attribute, as it currently sits, will break if the JSON contains any spaces.  You'll need quotes around it, at which point you'll probably want to HTML-escape it as well.

Comment: @abunour mysql_* is depreciated now use mysqli_* or PDO

Answer (score 0):

Basicly whenever you use ajax to post to a page, anyone with a developer console in their browser is able to see that request. And alter it as they like. Just like they can alter the `data-bind` attribute by using something like firebug.

You should implement checks on the POST variables in your page.php to make sure the input is not something you want inserted into your PHP code.